# How does angular.js validate the form in this example?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking at the example on this page: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_validate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Validation Example</h2>

    <form ng-app="" 
          ng-controller="validateCtrl" 
          name="myForm" 
          novalidate>

    <p>Username:<br>
    <input type="text" 
           name="user" 
           ng-model="user" 
           required>
    <span style="color:red" 
           ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">
            Username is required.
         </span>
    </span>
    </p>

    <p>Email:<br>
    <input type="email" 
           name="email" 
           ng-model="email"  
           required>
    <span style="color:red" 
          ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required"> 
            Email is required.
        </span>
        <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">
            Invalid email address.
        </span>
    </span>
    </p>

    <p>
    <input type="submit"
           ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||  
                        myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
    </p>

    </form>

<script>
function validateCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.user = 'John Doe';
    $scope.email = 'john.doe@gmail.com';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I don't understand is, there seems to be no validation code. I especially don't understand why the following line works:

```
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
```

But if I place a similar line to try pretend that the username is an email address, it ignores it. i.e. the following doesn't check that the user name is an email address:

```
<p>Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
<span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
<span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
</span>
</p>
```

Can someone explain this better ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thats because your `email` filed is type of `email` so it validates against `email` format.
and your username is just a `text` filed so angular will validate against just a `text` input not against a `email`

here's a simple [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aC3GcJon2dSxfL7fqrnH?p=preview)

In your case,
email field is required and should be a email,

```
<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
```

so angular will first check whether its empty if not it will check that the value is an `email`

But in 
text field is just a text

so angular will check only for empty or not-empty of the textbox value